# Taking rolling sum values of a column till its difference to another column is positive in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not sure this can be done in Bigquery or not. Anyhow, I've been trying to solve this.

Columns:
In this Total Inventory, the inventory arrives on that date, demand predicts sales, and the final inventory is the inventory remaining on that day.

I want to subtract the rolling sum of demand to the total inventory to get the final inventory until the value is positive; afterwards, it will start again taking the rolling sum of demand.

Code that I've written:

```
GREATEST((SUM(Total_Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date) - 
SUM(Total_Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date)),0)
```

Basically, this code breaks down as there is no condition on a rolling sum of demand which instructed it to stop.

After that, I had populate values 1,2..,n when the new inventory gets added. It helped me to partition based on arrival inventory; however, when the final inventory is positive from previous results and new inventory gets added, it didn't consider the last rolling sum of demand and start summing from that row.

The column where I impute 1,2...n: sort

Code:

```
GREATEST((SUM(Total_Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY Date) - 
SUM(Total_Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU, sort ORDER BY Date)),0)
```

For better understanding, I'm attaching the screenshots [Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNAuF.png), [Desire Results_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsoh6.png), [Desire Resuls_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TidcU.png), [Desire Results_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgSGn.png).
Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of data/code/results.  Please include it as formatted text, using the formatting options the editor provides.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.